# react-native-navigation: How to go to a special page without tab bar?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native.

I want to create two pages:

- 'Login': without tab bar
- 'Layouts': with tab bar.

I tried to show the 'Login' page at start, but it always go to 'Layouts' page.
How to show 'Login' page first?

```js
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
...

class App extends React.Component {

    ...

    startApp = () => {
      Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
          screen: {
              screen: 'Login',
              navigatorStyle: {
                  ...
              },
          },
          tabs: [
              {
                  screen: 'Layouts',
                  icon: iconsMap.home,
                  selectedIcon: selectIconsMap.home,
              },

          ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are difining your tabs there in `navigationOptions` you can pass `visible: false` for hiding tabbar on particular screen.

Check out this comment from github issue for more information.
Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/581#issuecomment-284248914